# Set status bar style programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode has an option "Hide during application launch":

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Is there a way I can set this setting in my code, so that I can automate the building of my app from the command line without having to manually check this box every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, since these settings are stored in Info.plist which is read-only in runtime.

For further purpose, I take my ipad project as an example, so the key that stands for that is:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden~ipad</key>
<false/>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to edit the info.plist file in the Xcode project?

You can do that with a shell script using PlistBuddy, see `man PlistBuddy`.

Or alternatively create an Obj-C Foundation tool (or perhaps swift, just for fun) and NSPropertyList.